# Entity Framework Auditing for 1 to Many Relationships and Capturing the Related Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF (code first) in our data layer we have a need to enable auditing functionality for entity changes.  I have been able to figure out how to successfully capture changes to value type properties using the Change Tracker.  I have also now I believe figured out how to get the information I need to log Many-to-Many Relationships.

My remaining issue is how to log 1-to-many relationships and capture the Entity Information.

In the following Entity let us assume that the Ethnicity has changed.

```
 public class Person
 {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public Guid? EthnicityId { get; set; }
      public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
 }
```

Behind the scenes in the SaveChanges it only gives you a list of Key Value pairs for the changed properties.  As such all you will actually get in this case is:  "EntityId", "{ A GUID HERE }".  I can log that the guid changed, but that information is essentially useless to the user.  What I need to capture is also the Display Name (Something all of our entities implement) and log that as well.

The only thing I can think of: (disclaimer this feels like a horrible solution to me)

1. Look at the property name.
2. If the string ends in Id but is not just "Id" then Trim it off.
3. Use the Trimmed property name string to get a reference to that type (Enthnicity in this case)
4. Use EF again to do a get by ID for that type with the Guid.
5. Cast the object as our base type which has DisplayName.
6. Get the Display Name and add it to the Logs.

I would really really rather not have to do this.  I can't imagine this has not come up before.  Is there no magic in there somewhere that will expose the underlying entity link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a good reason to do this specifically in code, I would recommend doing this through SQL Server Change Data Capture. It requires little effort in setup and does a good job. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx